# copying and retrieving objects to/from a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I have a object from a class that is being copied to a NSMutableArray. I do that 5 times. However, whenever I try to retrieve the objects from that array they are all the same.

Here's the sample code:

```
[myProperty setAddress:@"Av. dos Estados, 70."]; 
[myProperty setPropType:casaRua];
[myProperty setRentalPrice:1430.0];
[propertiesArray addObject:myProperty];

myProperty = [propertiesArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Price 0  %.2f\n", [myProperty rentalPrice]); //In this I got 1430.0

[myProperty setAddress:@"Av. das Nações, 10. Ap: 103."];
[myProperty setPropType:apto];
[myProperty setRentalPrice:450.0];
[propertiesArray addObject:myProperty];

myProperty = [propertiesArray objectAtIndex:0];//indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Price 0  %.2f\n", [myProperty rentalPrice]); **//In this I got 450.0???**

myP = [propertiesArray objectAtIndex:1];//indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Price 1  %.2f\n", [myP rentalPrice]); //In this I got 450.0
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems the array was overwritten with the addObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're re-modifying the same "property" object over and over again.

You need to either `copy` it or instantiate a new one each time before modifying it, after adding the previous object.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with a new instance each time. Can you explain why this was necessary? Why the use of the object didn't work without the myProperty = [[CTRentalProperty alloc] init]; every time?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are taking the same object from the array, changing the values, and putting it back in. If you wanted to copy it and add in another object to the array, you'd have to do something like

```
myProperty = [[propertiesArray objectAtIndex:0]copy];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it working with a new instance every time. I just didn't understand why did I have to initialize the object each time.